# tab information showing up as links to sections in the body

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm attempting to make tabs in a section in my body, but it's not showing up as tabs, but rather just links to sections of the text.

```
<div class="tabs">
   <ul id="tabsnav" data-tab>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#tab-1">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab Four</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab-1">
   <p> tab 1</p>
</div>

<div id="tab-2">
   <p> tab 2.</p>
</div>

<div id="tab-3">
   <p> tab 3.</p>
</div>

<div id="tab-4">
   <p> tab 4.</p>
</div>
```

In the CSS I have this:

```
div.tabs #tabsnav {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
text-align: left;
margin: 60px;
background: #000000;
width:300px;
}

div.tabs #tabsnav li{
display: inline;
}
```

I'm new to tabs, so if anyone could throw me any hints as to how to make them show up so that only one tab is visible at a time, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want only text1 to show when on tab 1, text 2 when on tab 2, etc? Or what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Where did you find this code? This looks like JQuery UI Tabs. If it is showing as links maybe you are missing some references?

Comment: tsHunter: Yes, that's what I'm hoping for

Comment: LcSalazar: Found it from basic help tutorials. Don't remember the names. I think I am, but I don't know what those references are. Was hoping someone here would know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use the :target selector in your CSS http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/